# Dealing with ConcurrentAccessTimeoutException in asynch methods

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, jakarta-ee, error-handling

With rest service a long running process is triggered. It makes no sense to run it in parallel, the main service is defined as Singleton with default concurrency management strategy. In rest, a response is sent immediately, just for notification, that it has been triggered. To archive it the method in main service defined as asynchronous:

```
@Singleton
public class MainService {
    @Asynchronous
    public void mainTask(){ ... }
```

To process async tasks in the application server there is a limit of a number of threads allowed to create. Until this limit is not reached everything is works fine. Tasks are triggered and queued.

But as soon as I reach the limit, application server throws `javax.ejb.ConcurrentAccessTimeoutException`.

In this case, I catch the exception and try in the response specify, that it has been triggered already.

```
@Path(ServiceRest.URL)
public class ServiceRest {
    @Inject
    MainService mainService;
    @GET
    public String trigger(){
        try {
            mainService.mainTask();
            return "Triggered";
        } catch (javax.ejb.ConcurrentAccessTimeoutException e){
            String message = "Already in progress.";
            logger.error(message);
            return message;
        }
    }
```

The problem, that I never catch this exception. I always get a message in response: "Triggered". But in the log, I can see in some cases:

```
11:42:00,308 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 4) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component MainService for method public void MainService.mainTask(): javax.ejb.ConcurrentAccessTimeoutException: JBAS014373: EJB 3.1 PFD2 4.8.5.5.1 concurrent access timeout on org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation@7be454f8 - could not obtain lock within 5000MILLISECONDS
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:100) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:52) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:439)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.processInvocation(LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.java:79) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$2.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:97) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:73) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

According the log, the `mainTask()` method is invoked internally by the application server. The `trigger()` already finished and returned a response. In case if there are no free threads/threads cannot be created to process a task, I get exception in the log, which I cannot catch.

Can I somehow find a workaround? I would like to avoid getting such errors in the log, cause in my case it is not an error? I have one solution in mind, but first want to hear some other opiniouns.

Answer (score 0):

When async method is invoked, it is invoked in another thread, managed by the application server, I cannot catch exception. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

I had to redesign my main service a little bit.

1. First of all, still one instance should be created, so it is
   singleton.
2. I keep state, when it has been triggered.
3. The main logic is run in async method, which is invoked only once at exact time. It is even not queued.
4. Cause 2 methods are involved now, I cannot use a default concurrency management strategy, so I applied by default @Lock(LockType.READ) annotation on it.
5. In order to run async method, it must be run via `that` self-proxy.

Here is a rest service:

```
@Path(ServiceRest.URL)
public class ServiceRest {
    @Inject
    MainService mainService;
    @GET
    public String trigger(){
        mainService.mainTask();
        return "Triggered";
    }
```

And the main service:

```
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class MainService {

    @Inject
    Instance<MainService> that;

    AtomicBoolean isTriggered = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void mainTask(){
        if (!isTriggered.get()){
            that.get().processTask();
        }
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void processTask(){
        try {
            isTriggered.getAndSet(true);
            ...
        } finally {
            isTriggered.getAndSet(false);
        }
    }
```

Probably there is a better and less complicated solutions, please let me know.